# Showing all time intervals on ggplot x-axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create yearly time intervals in the x axis of a plot in R but I keep getting the error:

Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

My data looks like this

```
 category start_date   end_date
    (chr)     (date)     (date)
1     A      2000-03-16 2011-12-31
2     B      2001-04-04 2011-12-29
3     C      2006-07-18 2010-12-08
4     D      2000-01-01 2006-12-31
5     E      2006-03-13 2008-11-04
```

I can draw a nice plot with this code:

```
ggplotly(
  ggplot(
    data = mydata,

aes(
  x = start_date,
  xend = end_date,
  y = category,
  yend = category, color = category
  )
      )+ geom_segment(size = 3) + xlab("Year") + ylab("Category") )
```

but my x-axis doesn't show all years. Here is the plot produced by above code:

[image: Here is the plot produced by above code]

When I try to add one more line of code (deleting one parenthesis prior):

```
 +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 
                       seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2011/1/1"), "years") )
```

I get the above error.

I've also tried:

```
 +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = cutoffs ))
```

Where cutoffs is:

```
cutoffs = c('01-01-2000', '01-01-2001', '01-01-2002', '01-01-2003', '01-01-2004', '01-01-2005',
            '01-01-2006', '01-01-2007','01-01-2008','01-01-2009','01-01-2010','01-01-2011')
cutoffs = as.Date(cutoffs, format = '%d-%m-%Y')
```

and I get the same error.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Yara

Comment: Does it work if you switch to `scale_x_date(date_breaks="years")`

Comment: You can add `date_labels = "%Y"` in the scale to get only the years on the tick label

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! I added: + scale_x_date(date_breaks="years", date_labels = "%Y")